# QGIS Raster Calculator with Python

Tags: qgis, python, raster, raster-calculator

I was wondering if you could help me with my problem. I want to execute a Map Algebra expression with the QGIS Raster Calculator. It would be easier to use the GDAL Raster Calculator, but since the rasters cells of my two rasters are not congruent, the GDAL tool ist not working. The reason for that is that I create a raster from a 3d polygon with TIN Interpolation and firstly the cell size is 0.999 instead of 1 and secondly I have no chance to snap my new raster to the old one. Maybe someone has a solution for that?

Here is my Python code and I cannot find the mistake :/.

```
ras_lyr1 =  QgsRasterLayer(input1)
ras_lyr2 =  QgsRasterLayer(input2)

entries = []
entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
entry.ref = 'dgm@1'
entry.raster = ras_lyr1
entry.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( entry )

entry2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
entry2.ref = 'flaeche3d@1'
entry2.raster = ras_lyr2
entry2.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( entry2 )

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31287')

calc = QgsRasterCalculator('(dgm@1/flaeche3d@1)<0',out11,'GTiff',ras_lyr1.extent(),crs,
ras_lyr1.width(),ras_lyr1.height(),entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot for your help!
Niki

Comment: Do you get an error message or just not the results you are expecting?

Comment: No, I get no error message. The process finishes without calculating the new raster.